# Overriding OnClientClick causing validation to fire multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, validationsummary

I'm trying to prevent a form from being submitted multiple time. It uses a validation summary so I am overriding the OnClientClick event for the submit button. It works as expected, the window showing the list of errors is being loaded multiple times.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
            Text="Submit" 
            CausesValidation="False" 
            ValidationGroup="vgApplication" 
            OnClientClick=" if ( Page_ClientValidate() ) { this.value='Submitting..'; this.disabled=true; }" 
  />
```

Comment: Well, trivially, since you run Page_ClientValidate() manually, this will cause the validation to happen a second time, in addition to the automated validation process. Try checking the boolean Page_IsValid instead. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside

Comment: @ADyson I have CausesValidation set to False.

Comment: try  CausesValidation="false" ?

Comment: @AntarrByrd only since you edited the question, which is after I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I have multiple ValidationGroups on my form. So I had to specify which ValdationGroup to run by passing in the name to `Page_ClientValidate()`.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
            Text="Submit" 
            CausesValidation="False" 
            OnClientClick=" if ( Page_ClientValidate('vgApplication') ) { this.value='Submitting..'; this.disabled=true; }" 
  />
```

Comment: that makes total sense, glad you fixed it